# iOS Orientation Change breaks Transform.translate

Tags: d3.js

I have a map powered with d3 that is basically structured as a div containing a background image and an svg. Zooming and scaling works perfectly until you change the orientation of an iOS device. The background image scales incorrectly until you trigger the the map to rescale itself, by interacting with it again (pressing zoom, etc). This only appears to happen on iOS.

Ive temporarily fixed the issue by modifying the translate function found in d3-zoom.

From:

```
translate: function(x, y) {
return x === 0 & y === 0 ? this : new Transform(this.k, this.x + this.k * x, this.y + this.k * y); },
```

To:

```
translate: function(x, y) {
    return new Transform(this.k, 0, 0);
  },
```

This corrects my problem on iOS and also does not appear to cause ANY issues with any other device including desktop browsers across OS'.

Im coming into this work without much knowledge in this area or with d3 in general, so Im wondering if anyone is familiar with this iOS orientation issue and whether I should be doing something different here - as I dont think hacking the library is ideal :). Id be happy to prove additional code if needed.

PS - I tried the 'normal' iOS fixes for orientation problems like the viewport tag etc